# Return rows from a PL/pgSQL function

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, plpgsql

I have a procedure in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_geom_difference()
RETURNS void AS
$$
BEGIN
SELECT filedata.num,st_area(ST_Difference(ST_TRANSFORM(filedata.the_geom,70066),filedata_temp.the_geom))
FROM filedata, filedata_temp
Where filedata.num=filedata_temp.num

end;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

I call it in Java and want to get result of this procedure. How to change this procedure to make it possible get a result? And how to work with it in JDBC?

Now I use this:

```
Integer fileId;
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
Connection connect= null;
connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgis","postgres","123456");
java.sql.CallableStatement proc =  connect.prepareCall("{?=call get_geom_difference()}");
proc.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.Integer);
proc.execute();
ResultSet results = (ResultSet) proc.getObject(1);
while (results.next()) {
fileId=r.getInt("num");
}
proc.close();
connect.close();
out.println(fileId);
```

But When I try to call the procedure in JDBC I get

> error org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred
>   processing JSP page /commit_changes.jsp at line 25

Line 25 is: `proc.execute();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Proper function definition

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_geom_difference()
  RETURNS TABLE (num mumeric, my_area geometry) AS
$BODY$
   SELECT f.num
         ,st_area(ST_Difference(ST_TRANSFORM(f.the_geom, 70066), t.the_geom))
   FROM   filedata f
   JOIN   filedata_temp t USING (num);
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

You are returning a SET of a composite type (two columns), you have to declare the the function accordingly. [`RETURNS TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) is the most convenient way to do this.

Be sure to table-qualify the column names in the query so they do not conflict with `OUT` columns of the same name.

You can use a [`language SQL` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html) for this basic query (or you could just execute the raw SQL), no need for plpgsql.

#### Call the function in SQL

```
SELECT * FROM get_geom_difference();
```

#### Do it via JDBC

I quote the manual [here](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/callproc.html#callproc-resultset-setof)

> Functions that return data as a set should not be called via the
>   CallableStatement interface, but instead should use the normal
>   Statement or PreparedStatement interfaces.

I also took this example from the site and adapted it:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute(" <function definition from above goes here> ");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM get_geom_difference();");
while (rs.next()) {
    // do something
}
rs.close();
stmt.close();
```

You could also use a refcursor. Read [more in the manual](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/callproc.html#callproc-resultset-setof).

Comment: Hey, nice! Somehow I had missed the `RETURNS TABLE` option and had been defining a record type and returning a `SETOF` those. You way is better. :-)

Comment: @kgrittn: Introduced with v8.4. I wouldn't want to live without it any more, makes working with table-functions so much easier.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But can you tell how to work with this function in jdbc correctly?

Comment: @KliverMax: I added some more explanation and links to make it clear.

Comment: Plaese look at last update of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859723/how-to-call-postgresql-procedure-in-java

Answer (score 1):

In your definition your function returns nothing `RETURNS void`.
If you want num data type just change to `RETURNS numeric`. Also, To make it worked, perform select into some numeric variable `SELECT INTO var` and add `return var` to the end of function.

Comment: add `declare tt numeric` before `begin`

Comment: Thank you its work. But Whan i try call procedure in jdbc i get `error org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /commit_changes.jsp at line 25` line 25 is `proc.execute();

Comment: Actuall performing SP exeution in java give your information what error is

Comment: This answer would work for a function that returns *one* numeric value, which is not the case for the function at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Although Erwin provided a great answer, I thought I'd share a version in which the function takes params, and I'm using the new postgres return query syntax within the body of the function. The difference is that it seems to set params you have to use the PreparedStatement interface rather than the higher level Statement.
here's my pg function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gettools(_userid bigint)
  RETURNS table(id bigint,itemname character varying(250)) AS
$BODY$

begin   
    return query 
    select distinct a.id, a.itemname 
    from tool a inner join tooltie b
     on a.id = b.toolid 
     and b.userid=_userid;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
  COST 100;
```

and here's my java that simply fills a map with data

```
  private static final String GET_DATASOURCES = "select * from getdatasources(?)";

    public Map<Long, String> getAuthDataSources(Long userid) {
        Map<Long, String> auths = new TreeMap<>();
        try {
          if (connection == null || connection.isClosed()) {
            init();
          }
          PreparedStatement cs = connection.prepareStatement(GET_DATASOURCES);
          // this is where to set the param ? for the function
          cs.setLong(1, userid);
          connection.setAutoCommit(false);        
          ResultSet result = cs.executeQuery();

          while (result.next()) {
            Long id = result.getLong(1);
            String itemname = result.getString(2);
            auths.put(id, itemname);
          }
          cs.close();
          connection.commit();
          connection.setAutoCommit(true);
          connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
          LOG.error("error getting data sources", ex);

        }
        return auths;
      }
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: While `LANGUAGE plpgsql` is fine (and a good choice in *some* situations), you don't actually need it. `LANGUAGE sql` does the job and is often the better choice for simple functions. [More here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)