# Pass parameters to view (set returning function?)

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, plpgsql

I basically have a pretty complicated view that currently returns what I want from last-week aggregations.

```
SELECT *
FROM ...
WHERE  t1.event_date >= ('now'::text::date - 7) 
...
```

Now I'd like to be able to make the same calculations for any given 2 dates, so I  want to be able to pass parameters to my view. Pretty much I want to replace the WHERE clause with something like:

```
WHERE  t1.event_date BETWEEN %first date% AND %second_date%
```

I think I should be able to do this with a set returning function but can't figure exactly how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create a **function**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) (sometimes called table-function, when returning a set of rows). There are many [(procedural) languages](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/server-programming.html), in particular [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html). In your case [`LANGUAGE sql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html) does the job:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_user_by_username(d1 date, d2 date)
  RETURNS TABLE ( ... )
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT ...
WHERE  t1.event_date >= $1
AND    t1.event_date <  $2  -- note how I exclude upper border
$func$;
```

Example for `LANGUAGE sql`:

- [Return rows from a PL/pgSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862936/return-rows-from-a-pl-pgsql-function/11867138#11867138)

Examples for `LANGUAGE plpgsql`:

- [PostgreSQL: ERROR: 42601: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605174/postgresql-error-42601-a-column-definition-list-is-required-for-functions-ret/8611675#8611675)