# Create recursive view with WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, recursion, sql-view, supabase, family-tree

I am trying to make a view for my recursive query, and use the view with a where clause to set a starting point.

```
CREATE TABLE dog (
    id int,
    name varchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE dog_parent (
    id int,
    dog_id int,
    parent_id int,
)
```

This recursive query returns what I expect

```
WITH recursive Ancestor_Tree AS (
    SELECT 
        mp.dog_id,
        mp.parent_id
    FROM
        dog_parent mp
    WHERE mp.dog_id = 26

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        mp.dog_id,
        mp.parent_id
    FROM
        dog_parent mp,
        Ancestor_Tree ft
    WHERE mp.dog_id = ft.parent_id
)

SELECT 
    ft.dog_id,
    mm.name AS Member,
    ft.parent_id,
    mp.name AS Parent
FROM Ancestor_Tree ft
INNER JOIN dog mm
    ON mm.id = ft.dog_id
INNER JOIN dog mp
    ON mp.id = ft.parent_id
```

Result:

```
| dog_id | member     | parent_id | parent         |
| ------ | ---------- | --------- | -------------- |
| 33     | Beniga     | 35        | Bunta          |
| 33     | Beniga     | 36        | Kaori          |
| 26     | Rei        | 33        | Beniga         |
| 34     | Ginga      | 37        | Gouzanhaou     |
| 34     | Ginga      | 38        | Ukigumo        |
| 26     | Rei        | 34        | Ginga          |
| 38     | Ukigumo    | 39        | Kumotarou      |
| 38     | Ukigumo    | 40        | Gintsurugihime |
| 37     | Gouzanhaou | 41        | Gyokuhou       |
| 35     | Bunta      | 42        | Koharu         |
| 35     | Bunta      | 43        | Chouhou        |
| 43     | Chouhou    | 44        | Kotofusa       |
| 43     | Chouhou    | 45        | Tsubomi        |
| 36     | Kaori      | 46        | Chacha         |
| 46     | Chacha     | 47        | Teruhide       |
| 46     | Chacha     | 48        | Sekihoume      |
| 36     | Kaori      | 49        | Kokuga         |
| 49     | Kokuga     | 50        | Kotokaze       |
| 50     | Kotokaze   | 51        | Seizanhou      |
| 50     | Kotokaze   | 52        | Houki          |
```

But I want to create a `VIEW` and replace the `WHERE mp.dog_id = 26` with a `WHERE` for the `VIEW` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM recursive_view WHERE dog_id = 26
```

This is how I tried to create the view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW recursive_view AS
WITH recursive Ancestor_Tree (dog_id, parent_id) AS (
    SELECT 
        mp.dog_id as dog_id,
        mp.parent_id as parent_id
    FROM
        dog_parent mp

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        mp.dog_id,
        mp.parent_id
    FROM
        dog_parent mp,
        Ancestor_Tree ft
    WHERE mp.dog_id = ft.parent_id
)

SELECT 
    ft.dog_id,
    mm.name AS Member,
    ft.parent_id,
    mp.name AS Parent
FROM Ancestor_Tree ft
INNER JOIN dog mm
    ON mm.id = ft.dog_id
INNER JOIN dog mp
    ON mp.id = ft.parent_id
```

But when I call it with `SELECT * FROM recursive_view WHERE dog_id = 26` I only get the parents for dog 26, but not the recursive part.

Result:

```
| dog_id | member     | parent_id | parent         |
| ------ | ---------- | --------- | -------------- |
| 26     | Rei        | 33        | Beniga         |
| 26     | Rei        | 34        | Ginga          |
```

How can I make the `VIEW` for this recursive query that accepts a `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For simple views, where an output column can be mapped to an input column directly, the query planner can push down predicates to input tables. (That includes all [updateable views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html#SQL-CREATEVIEW-UPDATABLE-VIEWS).) But in this case, the output column `dog_id` cannot be mapped directly to the input column `dog_parent.dog_id`, so that's not possible.

In the query you tried:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM recursive_view WHERE dog_id = 26
> ```

... the filter `WHERE dog_id = 26` is applied *after* result rows have been generated "recursively" (iteratively, really) - to the output column.

A [`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) is the **wrong tool** for your objective. You want to apply the filter *before* running the recursive term - to the input column. Use a set-returning [**`FUNCTION`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) or a [**prepared statement**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) for that. Like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_ancestors_of(_dog_id int)  -- !!!
  RETURNS TABLE (
    dog_id int
  , member text
  , parent_id int
  , parent int
  )
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
WITH RECURSIVE ancestor_tree AS (
    SELECT
        mp.dog_id,
        mp.parent_id
    FROM
        dog_parent mp
    WHERE mp.dog_id = _dog_id  -- !!!

    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        mp.dog_id,
        mp.parent_id
    FROM
        dog_parent mp,
        ancestor_tree ft
    WHERE mp.dog_id = ft.parent_id
   )
SELECT
    ft.dog_id,
    mm.name AS member,
    ft.parent_id,
    mp.name AS parent
FROM ancestor_tree ft
INNER JOIN dog mm
    ON mm.id = ft.dog_id
INNER JOIN dog mp
    ON mp.id = ft.parent_id
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_ancestors_of(26);
```

Related:

- [Pass parameters to view (set returning function?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483411/pass-parameters-to-view-set-returning-function/19483595#19483595)
- [Pass In "WHERE" parameters to PostgreSQL View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401749/pass-in-where-parameters-to-postgresql-view)